# APK checksum- Binary Code Protection

Tags: android, security, apk, binaryfiles

How can i calculate the CheckSum of my APK file in android? I want to calculate the APK checksum and compare it everytime my app. executes to see if some one has modified the binary code? How can i calculate check sum and achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Updated in 2020 - Google Play can now optimise, repackage and re-sign uploaded .apks (and add security [meta data](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/google-play-security-metadata-and.html) to the .apk) so it's unlikely this tamper check is still valid. Better to use the [SafetyNet attestation API](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/attestation) to verify the device and in turn your app - just ensure you're verifying the signature offline on your server.

Here's some code to checksum your APK. I wrote and [article](https://www.airpair.com/android/posts/adding-tampering-detection-to-your-android-app) on adding tamper detections to your apps (which ironically didn't include apk checksum).

```
private static long getApkFileChecksum(Context context) {
        String apkPath = context.getPackageCodePath();
        Long chksum = null;
        try {
            // Open the file and build a CRC32 checksum.
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(apkPath));
            CRC32 chk = new CRC32();
            CheckedInputStream cis = new CheckedInputStream(fis, chk);
            byte[] buff = new byte[80];
            while (cis.read(buff) >= 0) ;
            chksum = chk.getValue();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return chksum;
    }
```

You could also use this to can the sha-256 of your apk...

```
public static String getApkFileDigest(Context context) {
        String apkPath = context.getPackageCodePath();
        try {
            byte[] hashed= getDigest(new FileInputStream(apkPath), "SHA-256");
            return Base64.encodeToString(hashed, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;

    public static byte[] getDigest(InputStream in, String algorithm) throws Throwable {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
        try {
            DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(in, md);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while (dis.read(buffer) != -1) {
            }
            dis.close();
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
        return md.digest();
    }
```

Comment: First, thanks for your code. Is this answer still valid in 2020?

Comment: Google Play can now optimise, repackage and re-sign uploaded .apks (and add security meta data to the .apk) so it's unlikely this tamper check is still valid.